# Configure libraries for VS on different computers

Tags: visual-studio, svn, configuration, libraries, projects-and-solutions

How do you configure (i.e. set paths/libs/whatever) for libraries you use in your project (big ones, like boost/qt, which you can't just include in the project files) in Visual Studio when you work with other team members through e.g. SVN? I mean, everyone can have their libraries installed in different paths on their computers, so how do you configure all that to work everywhere?

Right now I'm working on a C++ project so I would like to know about C++ but probably the problem is general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically two options:

1. Put path to them into an environment variable, you can use then it in project properties
2. Create a VS user macros with predefined name with path to installed libraries, again it can be used in project properties

To me #1 seems to be simpler and more universal, but no clear winner.

You may also want to include library version into name of variable, so that information about required version of third-party components is versioned as well instead of "whatever is installed on computer".